# what is the difference two functions while and expected condition

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have two functions for actualy lookng for element that appear after sometime (something around 7 sec) so I tried to do it with expected conditions - visibility / presence of element with time duration of 10 sec and I got error that the element is not appear eventhough I saw it in other hand I did function :

```
public SafeModeScreen validateSafeModeScreen(){
 boolean flag = false;
 while(!flag) {
   try {
       System.out.println("The name is :" +driver.findElement(safeModeScreen).getAttribute("name"));
       System.out.println("The screen height is :" + driver.findElement(safeModeScreen).getSize().getHeight());
       System.out.println("The screen width is :" + driver.findElement(safeModeScreen).getSize().getWidth());
       flag = true;
       }
       catch (Exception e){
       }
      }
        Assert.assertTrue(flag, "Safe mode screen didn't appear");
        return this;
    }
```

the other function is:

```
public void waitForElementToBeVisible(By element, int delay) {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, delay);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    }
```

and that worked, what is the difference between them that the while worked?
Thank you

Comment: Please show us the first function that did not work

Comment: Not here, inside the question. Here it is not readable

Comment: Why are you using `wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);` again?

Comment: its inside a class and there is other waits over there so I restart it to my default time